# Communication problem between server and the frontend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, knex.js

The two functions in orderjs (frontend) work just with inserting the data to the database but after that, it gives me 400 res, and the page just reloaded itself and all the messages on the network just got deleted by itself so the loadUser funct don't work and the route change don't work also
the problem here is that the server shows that he sent the object that contain the object but the client don't receive anything
it receives a 400 res status but the page get reload itself so fast

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,
        Routes,
        Route
      } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';
import Home from './components/Home/Home';
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer';
import Order from './components/Order/Order';

import NoPage from './components/nopage/noPage';
import Collab from './components/collaboration/collaboration';
import Art from './components/art/art';

import OrderCompleted from './components/OrderCompleted/OrderCompleted';



const initialState= {
   
    user: {
      id: '',
      firstname: '',
      lastname: '',
      email:'',
      mobilenumber:'',
      adress:'',
      city: '',
      size:'',
      quantity: '',
      joined:''
    }


  }






class App extends Component {
 constructor(){
  super();
  this.state= initialState;
}
   

    loadUser = (data) => {
  this.setState( {user:
      {       id: data.id,
      firstname: data.firstname,
      lastname:data.lastname ,
      email:data.email,
      mobilenumber:data.mobilenumber,
      adress:data.adress,
      city: data.city,
      size:data.size,
      quantity: data.quantity,
      joined:data.joined
        }})
}


render() {
    return (
     <>
  <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Navbar /> }>
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="order"> 
          <Route index element={<Order  loadUser={this.loadUser}/>} />
          <Route path="orderCompleted" element={<OrderCompleted />} />
        </Route>
      
          <Route path="collab" element={<Collab />} />
          <Route path="art" element={<Art />} />
         
          <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} />
         </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
<Footer/>
</>
    );
  }
 

} 

export default App;
```

Order.js (frontend)

```
import React from 'react';
import MERCH from './MERCH.jpg';
import {Row, Col, Button, Form} from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './Order.css';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate} from "react-router";

function Order(props) {
   const navigate = useNavigate();


  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [mobileNumber, setMobileNumber] = useState('');
  const [adress, setAddress] = useState('');
  const [city, setCity] = useState('');
  const [size, setSize] = useState('');
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState('1');






 const onOrderSubmitCOD = () =>  {
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/orderCOD', {
      method: 'post',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        firstname: firstName,
        lastname:lastName,
        email: email,
        mobilenumber: mobileNumber,
        adress: adress,
        city: city,
        size:size,
        quantity: quantity

      })
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(user => {
        console.log(user)
        if (user.id) {
         
          props.loadUser(user);
          
          navigate('/order/orderCompleted'); 
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

 const onOrderSubmitCP = () => {
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/orderCP', {
      method: 'post',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        firstname: firstName,
        lastname:lastName,
        email: email,
        mobilenumber: mobileNumber,
        adress: adress,
        city: city,
        size:size,
        quantity: quantity

      })
    })
      .then(response => response.json())

      .then(usercp => {
        
        if (usercp.id) {
         
          props.loadUser(usercp);
          console.log(usercp)
          navigate('/order/orderCompleted');
          
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }



    return(
    <div style={{ width: '50%' }} className="center bg-black  b   br3 pa3 ma4  bw2 shadow-1">
    <Form className="font " style={{ width: '90%'  }}>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <Form.Control 
          placeholder="First name"
          value={firstName}
          onChange={event => setFirstName(event.target.value)} />
        </Col>
        <Col>
          <Form.Control
           placeholder="Last name"
           value={lastName}
           onChange={event => setLastName(event.target.value)} />
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row className="mb-3 mt2">
        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridEmail">
          <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="email" 
          placeholder="Enter email"
          value={email}
          onChange={event => setEmail(event.target.value)} />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridPassword">
          <Form.Label>Mobile number</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="number" 
          placeholder="Mobile"
          value={mobileNumber}
          onChange={event => setMobileNumber(event.target.value)} />
        </Form.Group>
      </Row>

      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formGridAddress1">
        <Form.Label>Address</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control 
        placeholder="Adress" 
        value={adress}
        onChange={event => setAddress(event.target.value)}/>
      </Form.Group>

    

      <Row className="mb-3">
        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridCity">
          <Form.Label>City</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
          value={city}
          onChange={event => setCity(event.target.value)}  />
        </Form.Group>

        

        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridZip">
          <Form.Label>Size</Form.Label>
          <Form.Select 
          value={size}
          onChange={event => setSize(event.target.value)}>
            <option>Choose...</option>
            <option>S</option>
            <option>M</option>
            <option>L</option>
            <option>XL</option>
            
          </Form.Select>
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridZip">
          <Form.Label>Quantity</Form.Label>
          <Form.Select 
          
          value={quantity}
          onChange={event => setQuantity(event.target.value)}>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
            <option>7</option>
            <option>8</option>
            <option>9</option>
            <option>10</option>
            
          </Form.Select>
        </Form.Group>
      </Row>
    

    
      <div  className=" gap-2 mt4 b">
     <Button onClick={onOrderSubmitCOD} className="b" variant="outline-light"  type="Submit" >
        ORDER (COD)
      </Button>
      
      </div>
      <div  className=" gap-2 mt4 b">
      <Button onClick={onOrderSubmitCP} className="b" variant="outline-light"  type="Submit">
            ORDER (CP)
      </Button>
     </div>
</Form>


</div>

)
}
export default Order;
```

server.js (backend)

```
const express = require('express');

const cors = require('cors');

const knex = require('knex');

const order=require('./controllers/order');







const db = knex({
 
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {
    host : '127.0.0.1',
    user : 'postgres',
    password : 'test',
    database : 'dosei'
  }
});





const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send('its working')
})

app.post('/orderCOD',(req, res)=>order.handleOrderCOD(req, res, db))

app.post('/orderCP',(req, res)=>order.handleOrderCP(req, res, db))



app.get('/collab' , (req, res)=>{
  res.send('its working collab')
} )

app.get('/art', (req, res)=>{
  res.send('its working art')
})




app.listen(3000, ()=> {
  console.log('app is running on port 3000');
})
```

order.js (backend)

```
 const handleOrderCOD = (req,res, db) => {
const {firstname, lastname, email, mobilenumber, adress, city, size, quantity} = req.body;
if(!firstname || !lastname || !email || !mobilenumber || !adress || !city || !size || !quantity)
    {return  res.status(400).json('no data to load')};
db.insert({
        
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname:lastname,
        email:email,
        mobilenumber:mobilenumber,
        adress:adress,
        city:city,
        size:size,
        quantity:quantity,
        joined: new Date()

       
    
    })

.into('orders')
.returning('*')
 .catch(err=>res.status(400).json('unable to order1'))
    .then(user =>{
        if(user){
              res.json(user[0]) 
        } else{
            res.status(400).json('unable to order1')
        }
          
    })
    .catch(err=>res.status(400).json('unable to order2'))
}

 const handleOrderCP = (req,res, db) => {
const {firstname, lastname, email, mobilenumber, adress, city, size, quantity} = req.body;
if(!firstname || !lastname || !email || !mobilenumber || !adress || !city || !size || !quantity)
    {return  res.status(400).json('no data to load')};

db.insert({
        
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname:lastname,
        email:email,
        mobilenumber:mobilenumber,
        adress:adress,
        city:city,
        size:size,
        quantity:quantity,
        joined: new Date()

       
    
    })

.into('orderscp')
.returning('*')

    .then(usercp =>{
        if(usercp){

              res.json(usercp[0])
             

        } else{
            res.status(400).json('unable to order1')
        }

    })
    .catch(err=>res.status(400).json('unable to order2'))
}



    



    

module.exports={
    handleOrderCOD,
    handleOrderCP
}
```

Comment: Try changing your `<Button>` type from "submit" to "button"

Comment: Your question is mostly a *massive* pile of code with rather unfortunate use of whitespace that doesn't make it easy to understand. Please reduce it to a [mcve]. Emphasis on the minimal.

Comment: If you're returning the details from the 400 errors from the backend, logging them on the frontend, but the FE is reloading too fast to read the error, consider checking the "preserve log" checkmark in chrome, which shows longs between reloads.